# What is the Ascii value that needs to be subtracted from char in my 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sorry as I'm not too sure how to word this but, I am making a very small and simple Chessboard that takes strings from another class and outputs them on the board. I am trying to use a 2d array to display a list of characters followed by their corresponding number (a-1 to h-8). The problem is, I get an error which says there is an exception in "main" index 99 for length 8. I am assuming it is because the Ascii int to char conversion is messing up in my array, but not too sure how to fix.

Main code:

```
public class userInputs

{
    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {
        char c = 'a';
        int i = (int)c;
        System.out.println(i);
        ChessBoard1 board = new ChessBoard1();
        board.setPiece('a',4,"Lemon");
        String x = board.getPiece('c',4);
        System.out.println(board.getPiece('c',4));
    }
    
}
```

Seperate class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChessBoard1
{
        String[][] grid = new String[8][8]; 
        
        public void setPiece(char row, int col, String piece)
        {
             grid[(int)row-96][col] = piece;
        }
    
    public String getPiece(char row,int col)
    {
        return grid[row][col];
    }

}
```

The issue is

```
 {
             grid[(int)row-96][col] = piece;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: >The problem is, I get an error which says there is an exception in "main" index 99 for length 8.
Doesnt look like ascii issue to me. looks like the 2D array has a size of 8 while you tried to access index 99 of it, which obviously doesnt exist. Also, name the exception you get. If you get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException", then what I said is exactly true

Comment: No it outputs "97" and then says"Exception in threated 'main'" and Index 99 out of bounds for length 8 at the location that it is, that's all it says, which is why I think it has to do something with subtracting 96

Comment: @WanttoBeScripter147: please don't *describe* the exception message. Instead edit the question to include **the full text of the exception message** (i.e. copy-paste it).

Comment: Then single-step through your program, and especially watch the content of your array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems, first that you need to subtract 97, since the 'a' symbol has 97 ascii value, and java arrays are zero based.

Second in your `getPiece` method, you will also need to do the subtraction:

```
    public void setPiece(char row, int col, String piece)
    {
        grid[row-97][col] = piece;
    }

    public String getPiece(char row,int col)
    {
        return grid[row-97][col];
    }
```

Comment: This works with no errors but the output is 97 and "null" when I want the output to be lemon in the grid coordinate a4. Any ideas?

Comment: @WanttoBeScripter147 sure, it is because in the main function you set the piece to the 'c' character and trying to get the 'a' character, just try to change in your main the following: `System.out.println(board.getPiece('a',4));` instead of `System.out.println(board.getPiece('c',4));`

Comment: Note that you can just use `'a'` instead of writing `97`. It'll have the same effect and be more readable.

Comment: Thanks so much! It prints out "Lemon". Is there any way of removing the 97 before this or hiding it? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @WanttoBeScripter147 as @Joachim Sauer mentioned above you can simply write `[row-'a']` since it will be treated as a number. about hiding it, there are many ways, but overall I think it is the issue with your current design

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are zero-based, meaning that e.g. a `String[8]` array has valid indices from 0 to 7.

So you have to subtract one more from row and column:

```
grid[(int)row-97][col-1] = piece;
```

And of course, you have to do the same in the getPiece() method.

Comment: Added this into the line and I still get the same error for some reason, the output is 97 and the error is the same thing

Comment: Besides learning the Java language, I'd recommend to get accustomed to using the debugging features of your IDE, esp. single-stepping through your application.

Comment: Thanks! I had another issue as well which I have now solved, this answer has been very helpful.